# Ruby don't want to change version or update ( MACBOOK PRO M1 )

Tags: ruby, rvm, rbenv

I have a problem with ruby I installed it from homebrew ( Ruby version 3.2.0 )

When I use the command `which -a ruby` it returns me `/usr/bin` ==> System path and not the Homebrew path

So I changed the path in my `.bash_profile` and `.bashrc`

Nothing happened, so I installed rvm to change my version and have a better management but there is a big problem with rvm I can't disable errors and it don't install Ruby version.

I did those commands :

```
export warnflags=-Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration=
rvm install "ruby-3.2.0"
```

And still have the

> Error running '__rvm_make -j8'

I tried with rbenv it doesn't allow to install new versions too

```
$ brew link --overwrite ruby
Warning: Refusing to link macOS provided/shadowed software: ruby
If you need to have ruby first in your PATH, run:
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH"' >> /Users/gwenauger/.bash_profile

For compilers to find ruby you may need to set:
  export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/ruby/lib"
  export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/ruby/include"

For pkg-config to find ruby you may need to set:
  export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/ruby/lib/pkgconfig"
```

Ok so thanks to @Stefan I understood that

```
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH"' >> /Users/gwenauger/.bash_profile
```

Was a command and not a raw text to cut in your ~/bashrc

But I tried rbenv and rvm they're powerful tools but I can saw that they don't work well with M1 ARM chip the simple way is to use Homebrew even if it's not the best way to achieve it

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code, commands, our text output. We don;t need to judge your choice of colors. Instead, add the text itself to your question. That allows us to copy things (and try them out), makes everything searchable and allows people with e.g. screenreaders to understand your question. You can update your quesiton by clicking on **Edit** below it.

Comment: _"I installed it from homebrew"_ – `/usr/bin/ruby` is the path of the system Ruby. Homebrew typically installs in `/usr/local` (Intel-based Mac) or `/opt/homebrew` (Apple silicon)

Comment: @Stefan Yeah I know I just wanted to show that even when I installed with Homebrew it doesn't change the pass even when I do it manually

Comment: Do you get the same error (or any error) when installing Ruby via Homebrew?

Comment: @Stefan No I successfully downloaded it but I can't set it as my ruby global version
"MBP-Gwen:~ gwenauger$ brew install ruby
Warning: ruby 3.2.0 is already installed and up-to-date.
To reinstall 3.2.0, run:
  brew reinstall ruby"
 I added an error to original subject

Comment: @Gwen did you set your `PATH` up correctly so it contains homebrew's `bin` directory before the system bin directories? Something like `export PATH="$(brew --prefix)/bin:$PATH"` in your `~/.zshrc` or `~/.bashrc`

Comment: @Stefan Ok so I understand the problem I got. I didn't understand that 
" echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH"' >> /Users/gwenauger/.bash_profile" was a command and not a raw text

Comment: @Gwen: Verify whether you are actually using Bash. Newer macOS versions use ZSH as a default shell. For ZSH, editing `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` won't have any effect. Here, you would need to edit your `.zshrc`. You can verify your current shell by running `echo "$SHELL"`.